# Ошибка в решении задачи по js. Итерация выводит все элементы, а не заданные

Tags: javascript

Ребят, при решении задачи у меня возникает сложность, подскажите, что не так я делаю? Вроде бы всё правильно делаю и задача не сложная, но что-то не так!

Дана функция, проверяющая числа на простоту:

```
function isPrime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
        return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

С помощью приведенной функции найдите все простые числа в интервале от 1 до 100.

Моё решение такое:

```
let res=[];

for(let i=1; i<=100; i++){
  if(isPrime(num));
  res.push(num);
}
console.log(res);
function isPrime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(let i=1; i<=100; i++){
  if(isPrime(num));
  res.push(num);
}
```

во-первых, в данном участке коды вы проверяете/пушите непонятно откуда взявшийся `num` - правильно/логично было бы проверять/пушить текущее число `isPrime(i)`

во-вторых, две строки:

```
if(isPrime(num));
res.push(num);
```

первая - проверка и пустое тело - в чём смысл? не стесняйтесь добавлять скобки чтобы не упускать подобные моменты

вторая - пушите число в результирующий массив, при том что это вообще никак не затрагивает проверку (строку выше)

То есть, должно быть как-то так:

```js
let res=[];

for(let i=1; i<=100; i++){
  if(isPrime(i)) {
    res.push(i)
  }
}
console.log(res);
function isPrime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: InDevX, спасибо за подсказку! Точно! Я скобки в условии забыл поставить, как только поставил - всё заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь поместить в массив переменную `num`, ее не существует, вам нужно передавать переменную `i` (ведь она принимает значение чисел от 1 до 100) в качестве параметра `num`.

```
let res = [];

for(let i=1; i<=100; i++){
  if( isPrime(i) ) res.push(i);
}

console.log(res);

function isPrime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
          return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: highpassion, спасибо за подсказку!